# gravitee and keycloak integration problem. error connection refused

Tags: authentication, docker-compose, keycloak, gravitee

im trying to get integrate keycloak to gravitee and i get connectio refused error when trying to log in with keycloak.

everything is running on docker container

heres my docker config

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2015 The Gravitee team (http://gravitee.io)
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
version: "3.5"

networks:
  frontend:
    name: frontend
  storage:
    name: storage

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:${MONGODB_VERSION:-6.0.8}
    container_name: gio_apim_mongodb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./gravitee/mongodb/data:/data/db
    networks:
      - storage

  elasticsearch-apim:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${ELASTIC_VERSION:-7.0.0}
    container_name: gio_apim_elasticsearch
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./gravitee/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile: 65536
    networks:
      - storage

  gateway:
    image: graviteeio/apim-gateway:${APIM_VERSION:-4}
    container_name: gio_apim_gateway
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - elasticsearch-apim
    volumes:
      - ./gravitee/apim-gateway/logs:/opt/graviteeio-gateway/logs
      - ./gravitee/apim-gateway/plugins:/opt/graviteeio-gateway/plugins-ext
    environment:
      - gravitee_management_mongodb_uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/gravitee?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=5000&socketTimeoutMS=5000
      - gravitee_ratelimit_mongodb_uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/gravitee?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=5000&socketTimeoutMS=5000
      - gravitee_reporters_elasticsearch_endpoints_0=http://elasticsearch-apim:9200
      - gravitee_plugins_path_0=/opt/graviteeio-gateway/plugins
      - gravitee_plugins_path_1=/opt/graviteeio-gateway/plugins-ext
    networks:
      - storage
      - frontend

  management_api:
    image: graviteeio/apim-management-api:${APIM_VERSION:-4}
    container_name: gio_apim_management_api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - elasticsearch-apim
    volumes:
      - ./gravitee/apim-management-api/logs:/opt/graviteeio-management-api/logs
      - ./gravitee/apim-management-api/plugins:/opt/graviteeio-management-api/plugins-ext
    environment:
      - gravitee_management_mongodb_uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/gravitee?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=5000&socketTimeoutMS=5000
      - gravitee_analytics_elasticsearch_endpoints_0=http://elasticsearch-apim:9200
      - gravitee_plugins_path_0=/opt/graviteeio-management-api/plugins
      - gravitee_plugins_path_1=/opt/graviteeio-management-api/plugins-ext
    networks:
      - storage
      - frontend

  management_ui:
    image: graviteeio/apim-management-ui:${APIM_VERSION:-4}
    container_name: gio_apim_management_ui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8084:8080"
    depends_on:
      - management_api
    environment:
      - MGMT_API_URL=http://localhost:8083/management/organizations/DEFAULT/environments/DEFAULT/
    volumes:
      - ./gravitee/apim-management-ui/logs:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - frontend

  portal_ui:
    image: graviteeio/apim-portal-ui:${APIM_VERSION:-4}
    container_name: gio_apim_portal_ui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8085:8080"
    depends_on:
      - management_api
    environment:
      - PORTAL_API_URL=http://localhost:8083/portal/environments/DEFAULT
    volumes:
      - ./gravitee/apim-portal-ui/logs:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - frontend

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION}
    command: start-dev
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    container_name: local_keycloak
    environment:
     - KC_DB=${KC_DB}
     - KC_DB_URL_HOST=${KC_DB_URL_HOST}
     - KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=${KC_DB_URL_DATABASE}
     - KC_DB_USERNAME=${KC_DB_USERNAME}
     - KC_DB_PASSWORD=${KC_DB_PASSWORD}
     - KC_DB_SCHEMA=${KC_DB_SCHEMA}
     - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN}
     - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "8890:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - storage
      - frontend

  postgres:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRESQL_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRESQL_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASS}
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    ports:
      - "5456:5433"
    networks:
      - storage
```

and my env file:

```
MONGODB_VERSION=6.0.8
APIM_VERSION=3.5

KEYCLOAK_VERSION=22.0
KC_DB=postgres
KC_DB_URL_HOST=postgres
KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=keycloakdb
KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
KC_DB_SCHEMA=public
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin

POSTGRESQL_VERSION=15.4
POSTGRESQL_DB=keycloakdb
POSTGRESQL_USER=keycloak
POSTGRESQL_PASS=password
```

this is what it calls after i fill in my login details to window that opens
[image]

heres request payload:
[image]

after checked logs gravitee management api spit error:

```
gio_apim_management_api | 05:45:34.694 [gravitee-listener-50] ERROR i.g.r.a.m.r.provider.ThrowableMapper - Internal error
gio_apim_management_api | javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:261)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:296)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:609)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:608)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:421)
gio_apim_management_api |       at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:327)
gio_apim_management_api |       at io.gravitee.rest.api.management.rest.resource.auth.OAuth2AuthenticationResource.exchangeAuthorizationCode(OAuth2AuthenticationResource.java:222)
gio_apim_management_api |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
gio_apim_management_api |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
gio_apim_management_api |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
gio_apim_management_api |       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Heres my gravitee identity provider settings:
[image]

this setting i also see in gravitee identity provider settings, but this address is impossible to change
[image]

let me know if you need more info. like client settings or realm settings

thanks
-Toni

Answer (score 0):

Your client is a private Client, you should provide "Client Secret", which I cannot see in your env file or anywhere else.

Comment: Client id and secret comes from keycloak

Comment: Yes, but you should incorporate these into your gravitee management api for connection to Keycloak, where do you configure this ?

Comment: ok i see. I think i found right spot for that. when i try to register new client in gravitee, it gives me errror: Client Registration provider is invalid or can not be reach, making impossible to create an oauth-based application.

im using this address as discovery endpoint: http://localhost:8890/realms/master/clients-registrations/openid-connect
i also tried to configure keycloak clients registeration settings.

but i think you pushed me to right track

Comment: ok i configured client registeration discovery endpoint as follows: http://172.21.0.1:8890/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration now its working when using docker ip and got right address :) 
still cannot login getting connection refused error still

Comment: The login page is served ? Give me more detail of your new error and process to obtain it  please :)

Comment: Any update here ? If it solved your problem mark it as an answer please